# how to get 150 chars only from one column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like

```
     business
----------------
id    business_name    description      metadescription
--------------------------------------------------------
1        A             BusinessA
2        B             BusinessB
3        C             BusinessC
```

Here I need to update a metadescription column. The value coming from description column
but metadescription column allow only 150 characters if more than 150 characters then it should take first 150 characters from description column.
In decription contains more than 150 characters so how can I restrict the column allow 150 characters?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the first 150 characters from a text then all you need is the `substring(string [from int] [for int])` function.

You would use something like the following

```
 SELECT id
, business_name
, description
,substring(description from 1 for 150 ) as metadescription
from yourtable;
```

Comment: UPDATE b2g_mns_v2.mst_business set seo_meta_content=substring(description from 1 for 150)  where business_id=OLD.business_id; this way written

Comment: @user2793872: not sure what you are trying to say. Any way the key thing here is the use of `substring` function. If that answers your question then you may mark it as answered ( click the tick mark).

Comment: Based on your syntax it looks like you're trying to do this in a trigger. Doing an update like that is likely to cause you some issues (in particular it won't work for inserts, only for updates, as OLD doesn't exist for insert rows). Instead you could just have your trigger body be "new.metadescription := substring(new.description from 1 for 150)".